# Hierarchical Treemap from scratch with no aggregation

Tags: javascript, python, r, data-visualization, treemap

hope you are doing well.

Let me introduce myself, I am a Junior Data Analyst and I allow myself to do this post on your group because I need advices.

The situation is as follows : I have Hierarchical data with more than two levels, and there is no sum from a child level to a parent level, each level is independant from the other (you can see the [csv file](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ujNevGh9GFG8Dz7H0FL_notNoXi599pG?usp=sharing) on the drive I shared).

The idea is therefore to create a Treemap visualization with drill down / up functionality to get an idea of ​​the value of each level / each sub level.

The problem here is that all the treemaps I tested (google Data Studio / Tableau / Python / R) are based on aggregation from a lower level to a higher level and in some situations can support only two levels, (you can see the [HTML file](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ujNevGh9GFG8Dz7H0FL_notNoXi599pG?usp=sharing) on the drive link I shared).

I searched a bit on the internet, and I found that we can define [our own Treemap from scratch](https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/Charts/HierarchicalDataStructure/jQuery/Light/),
On the previous example, there is only one level, can you please give me some tutorials / code snippets/indications that can help me build a hierarchical multi-level treemap that is not based on aggregation from a level to another?

I am grateful for the time you give me to understand my problem.

P.S: I am not a pro JS, but I am open to learn because the one who does not try anything has nothing.

Thank you community ^^.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I provided an example of what I want to do , you can check the HTML file and the web site link.

Best regards :)